# VMware player kernel module updater

Tags: kernel, xubuntu, vmware

I have installed VMware in Xubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, but when I open VMware, it gives me this:

[image: VMWare Kernel Module Updater]

I click "Install", enter my password, then this shows up:

[image: VMWare Kernel Module Installer]

And then it displays:

[image: VMWare Kernel Module Installer]

How can I fix this? I've already looked through some guides for installing these, but they were for older versions.

Comment: Well, what does the logfile at `/tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-9526.log` say?

Comment: @BingsF http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17018132/ There may be repetition, because I tried running it multiple times